# Renaming batch files for PLEX

Tags: shell-script, sed, rename

I am attempting to rename a batch of .mkv files from the original format to the preferred PLEX format. I am having difficulty with sed and with rename and with mv. I hope it is just a syntax error I am facing that will be easily resolved.

Rename BandOfBrothers.S01E01.Currahee.mkv to 'Band of Brothers (2001) - s01e01 - Currahee.mkv'

```
sed 's/BandOfBrothers.*.*.mkv/"Band of Brothers.*.*.mkv"/'

rename -v 's/BandOfBrothers.*.*.mkv//' ./Band\ of\ Brothers.*.*.mkv/
```

I'm having issue with just renaming the title, let alone the rest. If I can get it working once, then I will put it in a loop and adjust as needed.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to add the release date to many movies? If so, I don't see how a simple replace can help you. Maybe if you make a table of 'movie,release date' entries, a better script can utilize it to rename all the files in a nice, automated way.

Comment: I believe for PLEX, the folder only needs the date not the individual files.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` changes its input or contents of a file, not its name. It might be used to change file names when combined with other techniques, but there are better tools for the job.

`rename` seems to be one of them. Be careful, though, as there are two different *renames* around. The one that you seem to be using accepts a Perl substitution which seems pretty similar to a sed one, but there are differences.

Adding a slash at the end of a file name makes it a directory. That't why `./Band\ of\ Brothers.*.*.mkv/` won't match any file names - they aren't directories.

Moreover, in a regular expression (that's the first part of a substitution), `*` is not use the same way as in wildcards. It just means the previous thing is repeated zero or more times. Using `.*` in Perl regex means *anything but a newline zero or more times*. That's not what you wanted.

You can use two substitutions to simplify the process. The first one inserts the spaces and changes the capitalisation, the second one changes the season and episode format:

```
rename -v 's/BandOfBrothers/Band of Brothers (2001)/;
           s/\.(S[0-9]+E[0-9]+)\./ - \L$1 - /
          ' BandOfBrothers*.mkv
```

- `\L` means *lowercase everything from here*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. I will give utilize this info as soon as I can.

Comment: That method did work. I also discovered part of my issue is that I was using the command 'rename'. I needed to install the perl rename on my centos machine which is in fact 'prename'. Now that I have that installed, along with your syntax assistance, the batch prenaming is working. Thanks! If I had more rep I would upvote you.